# calculus: 'chain rule' proof involves cancelling but there's no fraction.

Tags: calculus

In lecture #2.6 Professor Leonard, in his proof of the chain rule ends up doing something like this:

```
dy   du
-- * --
du   dx
```

He then cancels the 'du' top and bottom to complete his proof.  But the 'dy/dx' form of indicating a derivative is surely not really a fraction is it?  If we use the Newtonian notation there is no 'fraction' at all.  The chain rule certainly works and you can see that the answer is the same as if you just distribute a polynomial raised to whatever power, however the above 'cancellation' seems very strange to me.  It it were a fraction we'd end up with 'something over something' but we don't -- there is no fraction so how can canceling work?  He just glosses over this so I hafta ask you guys.

Comment: That "cancel" method is not a proof, as you noticed.  So ... ask Professor Leonard.  Perhaps you missed some of what he said at that point?  Or perhaps he made a mistake?  Those of us here cannot tell which.

Comment: I'm watching videos on Toob, I can't ask him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your questions has been answered already.

Check the following links for more.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73492/how-misleading-is-it-to-regard-fracdydx-as-a-fraction

[Is $\frac{\textrm{d}y}{\textrm{d}x}$ not a ratio?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21199/is-frac-textrmdy-textrmdx-not-a-ratio)

Comment: Excellent, lots of meat on that link, thanks.

Comment: Sheesh. IS! ISN'T! IS! ISN'T!  I'd propose that the infinitesimal is like zero in that it never has any size, but unlike zero in that it can form real ratios with other infinitesimals that have been multiplied or divided by real numbers.  Thus dy/dx is a real ratio even tho both dy and dx have no size.  Isn't it just that simple?

Comment: If some points have not been covered fully, I advise you to look more in depth the meaning of _differential_. In fact, this can answer your question. Moreover, make sure you fully understand the meaning of infinitesimals.

Overall, explanation is kinda correct although mathematically quite "painful" to read haha.

Comment: Well, much to learn that's for sure.  Anyway it's interesting that this stuff is still being debated.

Answer (score 0):

These notations like $\frac{du}{dx}$ are just represented in fractions to ease calculations. Even in ur case u used fraction division to cancel out du. This notation just represent derivatives . We can't cancel out them like fractions so we just made their notation in a way such that one can use fractional rules to solve.

Comment: I didn't use fractions, the professor did and I don't like it, it seems very fishy.  And you can't have it both ways: if it *isn't* a fraction then you can't use fractional rules, canya?  You're trying to say there is no cake but we can eat it anyway.

Comment: If there was no cake only empty space then it would be hard for  *DUMB* people to eat. So we made empty space a cake so it is easy to visualise and to eat.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beginning to see that I should back off on this question, there's a bit of faith involved, at least for now.